# Store svg in browser cache and retrieve when required

Tags: javascript, html, svg, caching

How to cache `svg` in browser cache and get it from browser when same URL hits? I have tried both `<embed>` and `<object>` tags but, they don't work for me.

`svg` is created in `jsp` based on dynamic content. So, I hit URL using `<embed src="URL" />` or by `<object data="URL"></object>`

```
<object id="mainView" type="image/svg+xml" data="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Common/svg/svgDesignContent.jsp?layoutId=${seatTemplate.customLayoutId}&time=${seatTemplate.customLayoutModifiedDate}" style="min-height: 300px;"></object>
```

and also tried:

```
<embed id="thumbView" type="image/svg+xml" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Common/svg/svgDesignContent.jsp?layoutId=${seatTemplate.previewLayoutId}&time=${seatTemplate.previewLayoutModifiedDate};" class="thumbViewClass"/>
```

It's not being cached under the network tag.

Comment: You have 3 option. First is serviseworkers, you can control request from web page to backend. Second is iframe, this is rather workaround for older browsers. Third is set caching headers on your responce from backend and then just lie on browser cache features.

Comment: Perhaps after generating the `svg` you can save it as a `data-url` to `localStorage`? You can create a relationship between the generated `svg` and the `url` by building a JSON string with the `url` as the key and the `data-url svg` as the value.